# Деепричастный оборот и последовательность действия

Tags: деепричастия

Читая про медуз, наткнулся на предложение (воспроизвожу по памяти): «Втыкают щупальца, впрыскивая яд». Меня данная конструкция смущает, ведь здесь не соблюдена последовательность действий. Верно? Можно сказать: «Впрыскивают яд, втыкая щупальце» — что значит: «Яд впрыскивается после того или во время того, как щупальце воткнуто». Но если сказать так, как в статье, то смысл предстаёт следующий: «Медуза впрыскивает яд, и в форме сопровождающего действия втыкает щупальце». То есть яд уже впрыскивается, хотя щупальце ещё не воткнуто.

Правильно ли я расцениваю пример из статьи как ошибку, относя деепричастный оборот к событию хронологически более раннему, чем сказуемое?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я понимаю это так. Первая конструкция передает два одновременных действия: "втыкают щупальца, **при этом** впрыскивая яд». В таком случае все корректно. 
А конструкция "впрыскивают яд, втыкая щупальца" означает "впрыскивают яд посредством втыкания щупальцев". Тоже корректно.

Что касается медуз, то их щупальца такие же мягкие, как и все их тело, и не могут втыкаться. Но на щупальцах расположены стрекательные клетки пенетранты — остроконечные нити, которые втыкаются в тело жертвы, (при этом) впрыскивая жгущую субстанцию.

Comment: Вот как раз отсутствие "при этом" и вызывает у меня недоверие к этой формулировке. В языке много плеоназмов, но вот здесь для уточнения мне кажется "при этом" необходимым. Подразумевать можно что угодно, но мне представляется, что по факту тут логика описания действия нарушена.Думаю, точку в вопросе может поставить аналогичный пример или конкретное правило.

Comment: За уточнение про медуз отдельное спасибо.

Comment: Пример: *Поэтому он переменил позу, поднялся, зашел сбоку и передние лапы и голову положил на колени прокуратору, вымазав полы плаща мокрым песком* (М.А. Булгаков. «Мастер и Маргарита»)

Comment: Это деепричастие совершенного вида. Они воспринимаются иначе (если до сказуемого, то хронологически раньше, если после сказуемого, то хронологически позже). А вот как в этом случае, когда "делая сейчас я сделал то-то и то-то", "пуская яд, я воткнул щупальце". Такая формулировка вызывает сомнения, и пример из Булгакова их не рассеивает. Он несколько иной.

Comment: В примере в медузами глагол тоже несов. вида. Делая А, я делаю Б. Делая А, я делал Б.

Comment: Смысл зависит также от того, где стоит оборот. (1) Делая А, я делаю Б. (2) Я делаю Б, делая А. В примере с медузами главное действие - Б (втыкают)

Comment: В том-то и дело. 2 действия: А — щупальца, Б — яд. 
2 толкования.
1-е: действие А в точности совпадает с Б во времени. 
Но проблемы со вторым толкованием:
2-е толкования: действие А совершается не раньше и не позже, чем действие Б. Это позволяет действию Б свободно простираться во времени и до и после втыкания щупалец. Сформулировать следовало наоборот, поставив Б ограниченным длительностью времени А, чтобы впрыскивание яда происходило чётко во время втыкания щупалец. У нас же яд может впрыскиваться сколько угодно, хоть воткнуты щупальца, хоть нет, и нет уточняющего «при этом».

Comment: Про глагол несов. вид чего-то не понял. Причём тут «делая, я делал», когда у нас «делал, делая»? И причём в принципе глагол? Я про деепричастие. Делая — это как раз-таки ещё несовершённый (он может относиться и к будущему и настоящему), а совершенный (сделав) чётко указывает на то, что действие завершено. Во фразе «впрыскивая яд» — нет завершённости. Это процесс.

Comment: Я покажу ещё на примере:
Я завтракаю, собираясь на работу (работа — процесс, глагол — в нём частность).
Я собираюсь на работу, завтракая (завтрак — процесс, в ходе которого осуществляется сбор).
Аналогично и про медуз:
Вытыкают щупальца, впрыскивая яд (впрыскивание — процесс, в ходе которого втыкают щупальца, что, конечно, неправильно сформулировано и не отражает верной последовательности: «Втыкая, впрыскивают»). Было бы хорошо разрешить проблему ссылкой на правило. Пока, извините, я не могу принять ответ в текущей формулировке. Он мне не кажется бесспорным по изложенным соображениям.

Comment: Последняя поопытка вас убедить. Смысл зависит от места оборота в предложении. (1) Я гуляю, поглядывая по сторонам (или завтракая, как у вас). Главное - гуляю. (2) Поглядывая по сторонам, я гуляю. Главное -  поглядываю по сторонам. Смысла в этой фразе нет.